# if $2000 is 40% what is the remaining 60%

Tags: percentages

I am sure it is a simple equation, but I just can't seem to figure this one out.

if $2000 is 40% how do i figure out what the remaining 60% is in dollars

Comment: If $2000=.4\times x$ then what is $x$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I see you’re new here. If you find answers or posts good, hit the little blue arrow up (that’s called an upvote). It will move those posts higher in the feed and will reward their creators with points. If you find an answer that totally resolved your question, give it the $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ to move it to the very top and give the answerer an extra bonus.

Comment: @JackyChong: to be fair, that's *not* what the question asks. It asks "If $2000=0.4x$, then what is $\color{red}{0.6}x$?" No need to detour through $x$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I believe that’s why Mx. Chong posted a *comment* and not an *answer*. We also call those **hints**, because they *nudge* learners along he right path.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: the substance of my comment is that the nudge Jacky made is *to the wrong path*. To transform $0.4x$ into $0.6x$ one need not solve for $x$; one simply has to multiply by $1.5$. Your presumption that I missed the fact that Jacky's comment is a hint is totally groundless. Of course it's a hint. It's just not a very good one.

Answer (score 2):

### Method using ratios

Let the answer be $x$.

$$\frac{\$2000}{40\%}=\frac x{60\%}$$

$$x=\frac{\$2000\cdot60\%}{40\%}$$

$$x=\frac{\$2000\cdot3}{2}$$

$$x=\$3000$$

### Method using the total sum

Because $\$2000$ is $40\%$ of total, then $\$1000$ is $20\%=\frac15$ of total, so the total is $5*\$1000=\$5000$.

So, $60\%$ of total is $60\%*\$5000=\frac{60}{100}*\$5000=\$3000$.

Answer (score 1):

Percentages are *very* cool. As you know, $\%$ just stands in for $\times\frac{1}{100}$, but what you may not know is that to take a percentage of something, you just have to multiply by that percentage:

$$\text{$x\%$ of $N$}=(x\%)(N)=\frac{xN}{100}$$

---

So, call the total money $T$. Saying that $\$2000$ is $40\%$ of $T$ tells us that

$$\$2000 = 0.4T \iff T=\frac{\$2000}{0.4}$$

Now, to get the remaining $60\%$, take

$$(60\%)T = (0.6)\frac{\$2000}{0.4}$$

I’ll let you do the arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

If $\$2000$ is $40\%$, it is $\frac{4}{10}$ of the total.  So the remaining $60\%$ would be  $(\$2000/40)\cdot60=\$3000$.

Comment: Use `\$` to type a dollar sign in math and `\%` for a percentage sign.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor  thanks for he edit

Answer (score 0):

If $\$2000$ is $40\%$, then  $\$1000$ is $20\%$, hence $\$3000$ is $60\%$.